# Android. TranslateAnimation takes no effect

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create animation that moves an image.

Lets have a look at following (like image locations on screen):

- 01 02
- 03 04

If I move from **01** to **02**, **03** to **04**, **01** to **03**, **02** to **04**, TranslateAnimation works fine.

But when I do **01** to **04** I will have no visual animation, and image takes immediate vertical position.

Could you please suggest what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This works completely correctly if I configure animation in XML, but from code it fails.

Comment: Care to post your code? I am guessing one of your parameters is wrong and it for whatever reason it doesn't affect your other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the duration and interpolator? This code works for me (was struggling with the same issue tonight):

```
trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 100);
trans.setDuration(250);
trans.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
someView.startAnimation(trans);
```

Also, I found that most elements don't actually have a width or height when queried in an activities constructor, so trying to transform based on those is going to give you a lot of 0->0 movement (ie: none) If you are animating based on element dimensions you may want to do some logging/Toasting to make sure you actually have a width/height at the point that you create the animation.